# ETL and QA testing

Tags: testing, etl

I have few questions on ETL which I am not crystal clear which are as follows:

1)What are the components of test plan vs test strategy in detail?
2)What is the difference between ODS vs staging area in ETL? Are both present in ETL between source and target database (data warehouse) or only one present? If both are present which comes first?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @Eric Brandt: I did not get your question? Actually these were the asked to me in ETL testing. So, just wanted to have clear understanding about it.

Answer (score 0):

ODS : Operational Data store.
It is a collection of integrated databases designed to support operational monitoring. Unlike the OLTP databases, the data in the ODS are integrated, subject oriented and enterprise wide data

Staging Area: Which comes after ODS, where it cleans operational data before loading the
data into Data warehouse.